# Finiteness of wildly ramified cohomology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, ramification, global-fields, flat-cohomology

$\newcommand\p[1]{\left(#1\right)}\newcommand\Char{\operatorname{char}}\newcommand\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}\newcommand\b[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}$
Let $K$ be a global field. All cohomology below is fppf-cohomology.

Say $G$ is a finite type $K$-group scheme. Call a cohomology class $\alpha\in H^1(K,G)$ *unramified* at a (finite) place $v$ of $K$, if $\alpha\in\ker\p{H^1(K,G)\to H^1(K_v^{\mathrm{un}},G)}$ where $K_v^{\mathrm{un}}$ is the maximal unramified extension of $K_v$ (= completion of $K$ at $v$). Given a finite set of places $S$ (which contains all archimedean places) of $K$, let $H^1_S(K,G)\subset H^1(K,G)$ be the subset of cohomology classes which are unramified at all $v\not\in S$. If $K$ is a number field, then $H^1_S(K,G)$ is always finite, but this needs not be the case if $\Char K>0$.

I would imagine that finiteness of $H^1_S(K,G)$ can be recovered in the function field case if, in addition to requiring classes to be unramified almost everywhere, one also bounds the "amount of wild ramification showing up." I will offer one way of making this precise below. My question is if there exists a reference proving finiteness of something like $H^1_S(K,G)$ for global function fields which also takes into account higher ramification.

To make things more concrete, here is one sort of statement I could imagine one making. Assume $\Char K>0$, so I don't have to worry about dealing with archimedean places in the following definitions. Let $\Omega$ denote the set of places of $K$, and call a function $T:\Omega\to\mathbb N$ a *place function* if $T(v)=0$ for almost all $v$. Given a place $v$, and an integer $i\ge0$, let $I_v^i\subset\Gal_{K_v}$ denote the $i$th higher ramification group with the upper numbering (in particular, $I_v^0$ is inertia at $v$ and $I_v^0/I_v^1$ is the tame quotient), and let $K_v^i:=(K_v^{\mathrm{sep}})^{I_v^i}$ be the corresponding fixed subfield (e.g. $K_v^0=K_v^{\mathrm{un}}$ and $K_v^1$ is the maximal tamely ramified extension of $K_v$). With $G$ as before and $T:\Omega\to\mathbb N$ a place function, define
$$H^1_T(K,G):=\b{\alpha\in H^1(K,G):\alpha_v\in\ker\p{H^1(K_v,G)\to H^1(K_v^{T(v)},G)}\text{ for all }v\in\Omega}\subset H^1_S(K,G),$$
where $S:=T^{-1}(0)$.
Given the above setup, I would suspect that it is the case that $\#H^1_T(K,G)<\infty$.

Does anyone know a reference for a statement similar to the above in the literature (Of course, not necessarily made with the above definitions, but just something of the form, "cohomology with everywhere bounded ramification is finite")? I am particularly interested in references from which one can extract an explicit upper bound for the size of $H^1_T(K,G)$ (or whatever analogous object is defined in the reference), e.g. in terms of properties of $G$ and of $\#T^{-1}(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. I am also fine assuming that $G$ is finite (but not necessarily smooth).

Also, alternatively, is my intuition off and is there an example showing a statement of the above form cannot hold in general?